# how we do student T-Test?

Tags: t-test, exact-test

In my data water is control and gibberellin is positive control. We want do find the activity of steviol against water and gibberellin. How we do student T-Test?. My data of height of plant in cm is given below.

```
             Water  Gibberellin Steviol
Replicate 1   14       23         30
R 2           16       20         28
R 3           20       17         27
```

Comment: Can you just do a chi-square test?

Comment: Do you have some statistical programs available?

Comment: No, Statistical programmes are not available.

Comment: @StudentT A chi-square doesn't seem appropriate; these are heights, not counts.

Comment: Sidra if you can post this question you have access to the internet. This means you can use statistical programs. As an example, R is available for use this way (for example at r-fiddle.org -- I have even used it on my phone). However a question about how to do it by hand is perfectly reasonable; you could edit to say so. 1. How does this problem arise? Is it work for a class?  2. Do you have statistical tables? 3. Why did you choose the tag "exact test"? 4. Do you want equal-variance t-test / do you mind if you use the Welch-Satterthwaite (unequal variance) version of the t-test?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all You should make an ANOVA and then post-hoc tests.
Do not forget multiple comparison adjustments. And check normality of your distributions by chi-square or kolmogorov-smirnov test.

---

## UPDATE:

If you have no stat soft. Have a look [here](http://vassarstats.net/anova1u.html?).

The results are:

**p-value for ANOVA** 0.004109

**Tukey HSD Test:** 
M1 vs M2   nonsignificant

M1 vs M3   P<.01

M2 vs M3   P<.05

M1-water

M2- gibberellin

M3 - steviol

I would conclude, that steviol is definitely has effect and definitely better than gibberellin. The effect of gibberellin is insignificant.

---

## R-code

[R](https://cran.r-project.org/) is free to install, but if you have even such a strict limitations for software you may use [on-line implementations](http://www.r-fiddle.org/)

R code:

```
Water=c(14,16,20)
Gibberellin=c(23,20,17)
Steviol=c(30,28,27)
Table = c(Water, Gibberellin, Steviol)
n = c(3,3, 3);
group=rep(1:3, n);
data = data.frame(y = Table, group = factor(group))
fit = lm(y ~ group, data)
anova(fit)
pairwise.t.test(Table, group, p.adjust="bonferroni", pool.sd = T)
```

Have a look here for ANOVA and here for post-hoc.

---

**Update:**

## Manual approach

(I start to have pleasure doing different variants :))

So, if it will be helpful good description is here

```
             Water  Gibberellin Steviol
Replicate 1   14       23         30
R 2           16       20         28
R 3           20       17         27
```

Calculate N, sums, mean and sum of squares.

```
               Water    Gibberellin Steviol     Total
N                3         3         3           9
Sum              50        60        85          195
Mean             16.6667   20        28.3333     21.6667
Sum of squares   852       1218      2413        4483
```

Now we should calculate variance, standart deviation and standart error. Variance [calculated the following way](http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-find-the-sample-variance-and-standard-deviation-in-statistics/):

```
Variance=(SumOfSquares-Sum^2/N)/(N-1)
```

Standart deviation is simply square root from Variance. Standart error is Standart deviation divide to square root of N. 
**Important note!!!**

As we work under "pen and paper" conditions square root calculations are not obvious for everybody. [Here](http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/square-root-algorithm.php) is a very useful link how to **calculate square root by hand** (I also had terrible childhood without calculators).

So, now we are ready to fill the rest of Table

```
               Water    Gibberellin Steviol     Total
Variance       9.33(3)  9           2.3(3)      32.25
Std.Dev.       3.0551   3           1.5275      5.6789
Std.Err.       1.7638   1.7321      0.8819      1.893
```

**Total Standart deviation looks funny. You search for such a data especcially?**

**Fill in ANOVA table**

SStotal = the sum of squares of all the observations, regardless of which treatment produced them from the grand mean
In our case it is:

```
SStotal=(14-21.6(6))^2+(23-21.6(6))^2...=258
```

SSBetween = the sum of squares (deviations) of the group means from the grand mean multiply to N

```
SSbetween=3*(16.6667-21.6(6))^2+3*(20-21.6(6))^2+3*(28.3333-21.6(6))^2=216.6(6)
```

SSerror = the sum over the sums of squared deviations of scores around
their group’s mean. It is also obtained from subtraction

```
SStotal = SSbetween + SSerror,
```

which means

```
SSerror = SStotal – SSbetween=41,3(3)
```

Now comes **degrees of freedom (DF)** it is rather easy it is 1 less, then number of comparisons.

```
ANOVA table
Source       SS             DF               Variance Estimate   Fratio
Between      SStotal     number of groups-1       SS/DF         MSbetween/MSerror
Error        SSerror     TotalN-NumOfGroups            SS/DF
```

For our data it is:

```
ANOVA table
Source       SS             DF       Variance Estimate    Fratio
Between     216.6(6)        2          108.3333           15.73
Error       41.3(3)         6          6.8(8)
Total       258             8
```

**Perfect!** We have our F value for numenator DF=between=2 and denumenator DF=error=6. Now it is the most tricky stuff You should find a library with such a book:[image]

Their You will find p-value!

Comment: The downvotes are not mine, but one issue that may be the cause of them is that this doesn't explain *how* to do the test without software.

Comment: I add some information for pen and paper style